# Backing up a network drive to another network drive through VPN

Tags: vpn, mirroring, network-drive

I am having a network drive on location A. This location A has a VPN tunnel to which I can connect remotely. I am having another network drive on Location B.

Now I want to mirror all my files every night from location B to location A. I am unsure of how to do this or what is the way to go. I am also unsure if that is even possible.

Should I ssh into the network-drive and secure copy scp to the other location, overwriting existing files? Then set a cronjob? There is probably a better way to do this? Maybe I can use robocopy to achieve what I want? But it seems like it for copying, not mirroring files?

How could I implement something like this?

Hints, suggestions, advice and help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:  I am working with two network drives form QNAP which are two NAS units. I think they have their proper OS. I run both, linux and windows.

Comment: There are many, many ways to skin this particular cat, but you have to be more specific about what your requirements are and what platforms (O.S.) you're using. If you can't tell us what you want, we can't help you achieve it. Robocopy can be used for one-way or two-way mirroring. You could also use rsync as a very efficient and versatile mirroring/sync tool. The fact that there is a VPN in between the locations is irrelevant as long as both sides of the connection can reach each other.

Comment: thank you very much StarCat. Apologies for not being specific enough and make skinning harder :). I will update my question. What I am working with are two network drives form QNAP which are two NAS units. I think they have their proper OS. I run both, linux and windows. I found this just now (https://www.qnap.com/en/how-to/tutorial/article/how-to-set-up-remote-replication-on-qnap-nas/) but still unsure if that is the way to go or if there is a better solution to this.

Comment: @Micromegas Using `rsync` w/ logging would be more efficient than `RoboCopy` due to Rsync using the log to only transfer files that do not exist or have been updated to the backup location.  I'm assuming you're using OpenVPN in lieu of IPsec; if not, OpenVPN with [tuned](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/tree/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenVPN) configs would likely get better throughput _(encryption over AES128 isn't necessary since it's uncrackable)_.  Here's the [script](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/FreeNAS/rsync_backup.sh) I use to backup Zpools with `rsync`.

Comment: Thank you so much @JW0914. Very kind of you sharing this, that's very helpful. Ok so I will look more into Rsync since both of you recommend this. And yes I am using IPsec for the VPN of the local network. Location B has no VPN set up. Maybe I need to set it up before? Because I don't think I can reach the network drive on Location B without it, but I am not entirely sure yet

Comment: @Micromegas For data transfer, an SSL VPN [OpenVPN] is almost always a better choice for a myriad of reasons, such as supporting very large MTU frames _(i.e. if using AES ciphers [`AES-128-CBC` and `TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256`, etc.], the `tun-mtu` should be `48000` for the highest throughput)_,  All OpenVPN communication is performed over TCP, however each TCP packet is wrapped within a UDP packet for transmission, allowing for an enormous boost in throughput _(OpenVPN should only be configured to use TCP in its config if troubleshooting or experiencing high packet loss with UDP)_